# Issue with Unity Resources.Load() and normalization of filenames on iOS, HFS+, APFS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, special-characters, apfs, hfs+

On Unity, I have to load some resources that have special characters in filename, for example "è".
My approach so far has been to normalize the filename if I'm on iOS or macOS (otherwise load fails because file is not found)

```
#if UNITY_IOS || UNITY_EDITOR_OSX || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX
filePath = filePath.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
#endif
```

This approach works if Unity project source folder is HFS+, but fails if it's APFS.
Is there a way to make it work if source folder is APFS?
Assuming I keep using HFS+ forever, is this the correct way? Is it guaranteed to work on all versions of iOS?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question directly but our rules for resources, filename, etc. are always ascii lowercase only and underscore instead of space. Skips all the headaches.